# Is make_shared really more efficient than new?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, clang, libc++, make-shared

I was experimenting with `shared_ptr` and `make_shared` from C++11 and programmed a little toy example to see what is actually happening when calling `make_shared`. As infrastructure I was using llvm/clang 3.0 along with the llvm std c++ library within XCode4.

```
class Object
{
public:
    Object(const string& str)
    {
        cout << "Constructor " << str << endl;
    }

    Object()
    {
        cout << "Default constructor" << endl;

    }

    ~Object()
    {
        cout << "Destructor" << endl;
    }

    Object(const Object& rhs)
    {
        cout << "Copy constructor..." << endl;
    }
};

void make_shared_example()
{
    cout << "Create smart_ptr using make_shared..." << endl;
    auto ptr_res1 = make_shared<Object>("make_shared");
    cout << "Create smart_ptr using make_shared: done." << endl;

    cout << "Create smart_ptr using new..." << endl;
    shared_ptr<Object> ptr_res2(new Object("new"));
    cout << "Create smart_ptr using new: done." << endl;
}
```

Now have a look at the output, please:

> Create smart_ptr using make_shared...
>
> Constructor make_shared
>
> Copy constructor...
>
> Copy constructor...
>
> Destructor
>
> Destructor
>
> Create smart_ptr using make_shared: done.
>
> Create smart_ptr using new...
>
> Constructor new
>
> Create smart_ptr using new: done.
>
> Destructor
>
> Destructor

It appears that `make_shared` is calling the copy constructor two times. If I allocate memory for an `Object` using a regular `new` this does not happen, only one `Object` is constructed.

What I am wondering about is the following. I heard that `make_shared` is supposed to be more efficient than using `new`<sup>([1](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared), [2](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/GoingNative-2012/STL11-Magic-Secrets))</sup>. One reason is because `make_shared` allocates the reference count together with the object to be managed in the same block of memory. OK, I got the point. This is of course more efficient than two separate allocation operations.

On the contrary I don't understand why this has to come with the cost of two calls to the copy constructor of `Object`. Because of this I am not convinced that `make_shared` is more efficient than allocation using `new` in *every* case. Am I wrong here? Well OK, One could implement a move constructor for `Object` but still I am not sure whether this this is more efficient than just allocating `Object` through `new`. At least not in every case. It would be true if copying `Object` is less expensive than allocating memory for a reference counter. But the `shared_ptr`-internal reference counter could be implemented using a couple of primitive data types, right?

Can you help and explain why `make_shared` is the way to go in terms of efficiency, despite the outlined copy overhead?

Comment: What do you think `auto` means?

Comment: What compile options did you use?  Are all those copy constructor calls still there when you enable optimization?

Comment: Before you test the speed of a C++11 function, you should probably implement a *move* constructor in your class and make that fully C++11ish.

Comment: That code doesn't match the output.  The code you show leaks.

Comment: To echo @peachykeen, by adding a copy constructor you inhibited the automatic generation of a move constructor. If you want a proper test, you should add a move constructor and move-assignment operator yourself.

Comment: I don't believe your output. With GCC 4.6.2, I get [this much saner output](http://pastebin.com/T857Mmv2).

Comment: What difference would that make, @Ildjarn? Nothing in this code should be triggering a move *or* a copy of any `Object` instance. The code simply doesn't match the reported output.

Comment: @Rob : "Should" aside, without a move constructor there may be copies that occur that would have otherwise been moves, so counting copies without a move constructor is pointless.

Comment: and what @ildjarn said is particularly important when you're using C++11 STL functions, as they may be optimized when the appropriate C++11 features/methods/ctors are present (my original point). Testing half C++11 and half C++03 is going to break the optimizations in both.

Comment: @peachykeen @lidjam I think what @Rob is saying is that only the _pointer_ (smart or otherwise) needs to be copy/move constructed in the code provided, not the _object_.  The compiler doesn't ever need to consider whether copy elision or move semantics should apply to the instance of `Object`.  This can be shown by [making the copy/move constructors private](http://ideone.com/98dUh).  Bottom line is that the code doesn't match the output.  @user1212354 Either you've discovered a **massive** library or compiler defect or you're leaving something out.

Comment: I've edited the question to modify the code in the original block. On Stack Overflow, rather than making a new second with edits it's generally accepted to just change the post -- if people want to see how the post has been edited, they can always see the revision history. Separate EDIT blocks make the post harder to read, in general; in this specific case, it's not much, but just editing the original code block to be fixed doesn't hurt anything and makes things easier to read and grok as you go instead of having to go back and reread with the edit in mind.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

> As infrastructure I was using llvm/clang 3.0 along with the llvm std c++ library within XCode4.

Well that appears to be your problem. The C++11 standard states the following requirements for `make_shared<T>` (and `allocate_shared<T>`), in section 20.7.2.2.6:

> Requires: The expression ::new (pv) T(std::forward(args)...), where pv has type void* and points to storage suitable to hold an object of type T, shall be well formed. A shall be an allocator (17.6.3.5). The copy constructor and destructor of A shall not throw exceptions.

`T` is *not* required to be copy-constructable. Indeed, `T` isn't even required to be non-placement-new constructable. It is only required to be constructable in-place. This means that the only thing that `make_shared<T>` can do with `T` is `new` it in-place.

So the results you get are not consistent with the standard. LLVM's libc++ is broken in this regard. File a bug report.

For reference, here's what happened when I took your code into VC2010:

```
Create smart_ptr using make_shared...
Constructor make_shared
Create smart_ptr using make_shared: done.
Create smart_ptr using new...
Constructor new
Create smart_ptr using new: done.
Destructor
Destructor
```

I also ported it to Boost's original `shared_ptr` and `make_shared`, and I got the same thing as VC2010.

I'd suggest filing a bug report, as libc++'s behavior is broken.

Comment: "The results you get are entirely consistent with what the C++ standard allows."  I don't see anything in the code that should cause the instance of `Object` to be copy/move constructed (regardless of whether or not the compiler opts to elide such a construction.)

Comment: @AndrewDurward: Actually, you're right and wrong. The standard's requirements on `make_shared<T>` do not state that `T` must be copy constructable. Therefore, `make_shared<T>` *cannot* call the copy constructor. You're wrong in that if the standard did allow `T` to be copy constructable that an implementation of `make_shared<T>` could call it.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Thanks for the bug report against libc++.  I agree with your analysis.  This has been fixed in the libc++ public svn trunk and the copy constructor is no longer called.

Comment: I have copy constructor implicitly deleted because I defined a user-declared move constructor. Now clang complains about `make_shared` call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor. So if `make_shared` does not need the copy constructor, is this a bug?

Comment: I was passing a temporary to `make_shared` like `std:make_shared(M(..))` changed it ot `std:make_shared(std:move(M(..)))` and it is good now.

Answer (score 34):

You have to compare these two versions:

```
std::shared_ptr<Object> p1 = std::make_shared<Object>("foo");
std::shared_ptr<Object> p2(new Object("foo"));
```

In your code, the second variable is just a naked pointer, not a shared pointer at all.

---

Now on the meat. `make_shared` **is** (in practice) more efficient, because it allocates the reference control block together with the actual object in one single dynamic allocation. By contrast, the constructor for `shared_ptr` that takes a naked object pointer must allocate *another* dynamic variable for the reference count. The trade-off is that `make_shared` (or its cousin `allocate_shared`) does not allow you to specify a custom deleter, since the allocation is performed by the allocator.

(This does not affect the construction of the object itself. From `Object`'s perspective there is no difference between the two versions. What's more efficient is the shared pointer itself, not the managed object.)

Comment: "make_shared is (in practice) more efficient, because it allocates the reference control block together with the actual object in one single dynamic allocation". I think that is only the case for VS2012, they do this optimization, but linux std-libs don't do that optimization (yet?).

Comment: @Ela782: Yes, GCC has done so for some time. This is explicitly recommended by the standard in 20.7.2.2.6/6.

Comment: So this efficiency only happens in initialization of shared_ptr?Is there any efficiency in latter usage of ptr created by make_shared?

Comment: @bigxiao: There shouldn't be. A good implementation will store the actual pointer to the object at the beginning of the shared_ptr regardless of how the shared_ptr was created, so that dereferencing never requires more computation than it would for a raw pointer. The final deallocation differs, of course (especially in the presence of weak pointers).

Comment: @KerrekSB `make_shared` stores the object and ref countings together(in the same control block),so maybe there are less cache miss.

Comment: @bigxiao: Sure, but the most important operation of a smart pointer, i.e. dereferencing, doesn't require access of the control block.

Comment: "...the second variable is just a naked pointer, not a shared pointer at all." Wait what? Really? How can that be?

Answer (score 6):

So one thing to keep in mind is your optimization settings. Measuring performance, particularly with regard to c++ is **meaningless** without optimizations enabled. I don't know if you did in fact compile with optimizations, so I thought it was worth mentioning.

That said, what you are measuring with this test is **not** a way that `make_shared` is more efficient. Simply put, you are measuring the wrong thing :-P.

Here's the deal. Normally, when you create  shared pointer, it has at least 2 data members (possibly more). One for the pointer, and one for the reference count. This reference count is allocated on the heap (so that it can be shared among `shared_ptr` with different lifetimes...that's the point after all!)

So if you are creating an object with something like `std::shared_ptr<Object> p2(new Object("foo"));` There are at least **2** calls to `new`. One for `Object` and one for the reference count object.

`make_shared` has the option (i'm not sure it has to), to do a single `new` which is big enough to hold the object pointed to and the reference count in the same contiguous block. Effectively allocating an object that looks something like this (illustrative, not literally what it is).

```
struct T {
    int reference_count;
    Object object;
};
```

Since the reference count and the object's lifetimes are tied together (it doesn't make sense for one to live longer than the other). This whole block can be `delete`d at the same time as well.

So the efficiency is in allocations, not in copying (which I suspect had to do with optimization more than anything else).

To be clear, this is what boost has to say on about `make_shared`

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/smart_ptr/make_shared.html

> Besides convenience and style, such a function is also exception safe
>   and considerably faster because it can use a single allocation for
>   both the object and its corresponding control block, eliminating a
>   significant portion of shared_ptr's construction overhead. This
>   eliminates one of the major efficiency complaints about shared_ptr.

Comment: A minor nit, the Object instance can die before the refc control block i.e. if weak_ptrs are used. This isn't a problem, except the minor issue that memory directly held by Object's layout is not reclaimed until the control block dies too; in an ordinary shared_ptr the object's heap block can be reclaimed as soon as it expires.

Answer (score 3):

You should not be getting any extra copies there. The output should be:

```
Create smart_ptr using make_shared...
Constructor make_shared
Create smart_ptr using make_shared: done.
Create smart_ptr using new...
Constructor new
Create smart_ptr using new: done.
Destructor
```

I don't know why you're getting extra copies. (though I see you're getting one 'Destructor' too many, so the code you used to get your output must be different from the code you posted)

`make_shared` is more efficient because it can be implemented using only one dynamic allocation instead of two, and because it needs one pointer's worth of memory less book-keeping per shared object.

Edit: I didn't check with Xcode 4.2 but with Xcode 4.3 I get the correct output I show above, not the incorrect output shown in the question.

Comment: Talk about good timing! ;-)  Thanks for the Xcode 4.3 report.