# Differences between std::make_unique and std::unique_ptr with new

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

Does `std::make_unique` have any efficiency benefits like `std::make_shared`?

Compared to manually constructing `std::unique_ptr`:

```
std::make_unique<int>(1);         // vs
std::unique_ptr<int>(new int(1));
```

Comment: Does `make_shared` have any efficiency over just writing the long hand code?

Comment: @EdHeal It may, because `make_shared` can allocate both the space for the object and the space for the control block together in a single allocation. The cost of that is that the object cannot be deallocated separately from the control block, so if you use `weak_ptr` a lot then you may end up using more memory.

Comment: Perhaps this is a good starting point http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9302296/is-make-shared-really-more-efficient-than-new

Comment: See this link for detailed explanation: https://herbsutter.com/gotw/_102/

Answer (score 199, accepted):

The motivation behind `make_unique` is primarily two-fold:

- `make_unique` is safe for creating temporaries, whereas with explicit use of `new` you have to remember the rule about not using unnamed temporaries.

  ```
  foo(make_unique<T>(), make_unique<U>()); // exception safe

  foo(unique_ptr<T>(new T()), unique_ptr<U>(new U())); // unsafe*
  ```
- The addition of `make_unique` finally means we can tell people to 'never' use `new` rather than the previous rule to "'never' use `new` except when you make a `unique_ptr`".

There's also a third reason:

- `make_unique` does not require redundant type usage. `unique_ptr<T>(new T())` -> `make_unique<T>()`

None of the reasons involve improving runtime efficiency the way using `make_shared` does (due to avoiding a second allocation, at the cost of potentially higher peak memory usage).

* It is expected that C++17 will include a rule change that means that this is no longer unsafe. See C++ committee papers [P0400R0](http://wg21.link/p0400r0) and [P0145R3](http://wg21.link/p0145r3).

Comment: It would make more sense to say `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr` are why we can tell people to "never use `new`."

Comment: @TimothyShields Yeah, that's what I mean. It's just that in C++11 we have `make_shared` and so `make_unique` is the final piece that was previously missing.

Comment: Any way you could mention briefly, or link to, the reason for not using unnamed temporaries?

Comment: Actually, from http://stackoverflow.com/a/19472607/368896, I've got it... From that answer, consider the following function call `f`: `f(unique_ptr<T>(new T), function_that_can_throw());` - to quote the answer: *The compiler is allowed to call (in order): `new T`, `function_that_can_throw()`, `unique_ptr<T>(...)`.  Obviously if `function_that_can_throw` actually throws then you leak. `make_unique` prevents this case.*  So, my question is answered.

Comment: @bames53 Unfortunately there is still need to use raw `new` if you want to pass a custom facet to [`std::locale`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/locale/locale) (overload 7).

Comment: @bames53 Have there been any news regarding the footnote?

Comment: @tambre The linked papers are part of the C++17 draft, and there shouldn't be any significant changes between now and publication later this year. Clang already implements these rules. It's not clear from gcc's status page if they do or not yet.

Comment: Took a really long time to see why it is now safe, but yeah it is. BTW thanks for updating your answer

Comment: One reason I once had to use std::unique_ptr<T>(new T()) was because the constructor of T was private.  Even if the call to std::make_unique was in a public factory method of class T, it didn't compile because one of the underlying methods of std::make_unique could not access the private constructor.  I didn't want to make that method friend because I didn't want to rely on the implementation of std::make_unique.  So the only solution was, calling new in my factory method of class T, and then wrap it in an std::unique_ptr<T>.

Answer (score 24):

`std::make_unique` and `std::make_shared` are there for two reasons:

1. So that you don't have to explicitly list the template type arguments.
2. Additional exception safety over using `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` constructors.  (See the Notes section [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared).)

It's not really about runtime efficiency. There is the bit about the control block and the `T` being allocated all at once, but I think that's more a bonus and less a motivation for these functions to exist.

Comment: They're also there for exception-safety.

Comment: @0x499602D2 And that, good addition. [This page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared) talks about that.

Comment: For future readers, C++17 does not allow for interleaving of function arguments so the argument for exception-safety doesn't hold anymore. The memory allocation for two parallel `std::make_shared` will ensure that at least one of them gets wrapped in the smart pointer before the other memory allocation occurs, hence no leaks.

Answer (score 19):

A reason why you would have to use `std::unique_ptr(new A())` or `std::shared_ptr(new A())` directly instead of `std::make_*()` is being unable to access the constructor of class `A` outside of current scope.

Comment: Is there a plan to fix C++ so make_unique and make_shared can access private constructors?

Comment: @nyanpasu64 make_unique needs no fixing. You can always make it a friend of your class with a private constructor.

Answer (score 7):

Consider function call

```
void function(std::unique_ptr<A>(new A()), std::unique_ptr<B>(new B())) { ... }
```

Suppose that `new A()` succeeds, but `new B()` throws an exception: you catch it to resume the normal execution of your program. Unfortunately, the C++ standard does not require that object `A` gets destroyed and its memory deallocated: memory silently leaks and there's no way to clean it up. By wrapping `A` and `B` into `std::make_unique()` calls, you are sure the leak will not occur:

```
void function(std::make_unique<A>(), std::make_unique<B>()) { ... }
```

The point here is that `std::make_unique<A>()` and `std::make_unique<B>()` return temporary objects, and cleanup of temporary objects is correctly specified in the C++ standard: their destructors will be triggered and the memory freed. So, if you can, always prefer to allocate objects using `std::make_unique()` and `std::make_shared()`.