# Custom erase for c++ set or other collection

Tags: c++, design-patterns, stl, c++14

I want to do something like this:

```
std::set<my_type*> s;

s.insert(new my_type(...));
...
s.erase(...);
```

Where the set's erase will delete the pointer to avoid a memory leak.

Is this possible with C++ containers or would the proper solution be to subclass the container and write my own erase, or use some sort of smart pointer scheme?

Comment: What's wrong with a smart pointer?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with a smart pointer, I want to know if there is a way  that requires less engineering.

Comment: `set<unique_ptr<my_type>> s; s.insert (make_unique<my_type> (...));` does not seem more engineering to me than your code.

Comment: You mean `std::set<my_type*> s;`, yes?

Comment: @user318904 Smart pointers are in c++14, so as JohnB points out it's hardly any engineering. Subclassing the standard collection classes is [seldom the correct approach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6806173/subclass-inherit-standard-containers).

Comment: No, I mean `std::set<std::unique_ptr<my_type>> s;`.

Comment: Sorry, @JohnB that comment was meant for OP. It looked like they'd left out the `*` in the question

Comment: @user318904: I guess what you really want is a `std::set<my_type>`, or even a `std::vector<my_type>` and use `emplace`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `set` is declared to store `my_type`, but you're sending it `my_type*`, so the code is inconsistent as is. In any event, if you don't need heap allocation, don't use it:

```
std::set<my_type> s;

// Emplace improves on s.insert(my_type(...)); by allowing construction in place
// to minimize move/copy work
s.emplace(...args for my_type...);
...
s.erase(...);
```

With no heap allocation, your `my_type` destructor is called and no `delete` is needed for its own structure (or more precisely, `set` manages that internally).

If you need heap allocation, use smart pointers so deletion implies freeing (and [`std::make_unique` makes this cleaner and lets you completely avoid all use of `new` and `delete`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22571202/364696)):

```
std::set<std::unique_ptr<my_type>> s;

s.insert(std::make_unique<my_type>(...));
...
s.erase(...);
```