# Why does unique_ptr instantiation compile to larger binary than raw pointer?

Tags: c++, assembly, smart-pointers

I was always under the impression that a `std::unique_ptr` had no overhead compared to using a raw pointer. However, compiling the following code

```
#include <memory>

void raw_pointer() {
  int* p = new int[100];
  delete[] p;
}

void smart_pointer() {
  auto p = std::make_unique<int[]>(100);
}
```

with `g++ -std=c++14 -O3` produces the following assembly:

```
raw_pointer():
        sub     rsp, 8
        mov     edi, 400
        call    operator new[](unsigned long)
        add     rsp, 8
        mov     rdi, rax
        jmp     operator delete[](void*)
smart_pointer():
        sub     rsp, 8
        mov     edi, 400
        call    operator new[](unsigned long)
        lea     rdi, [rax+8]
        mov     rcx, rax
        mov     QWORD PTR [rax], 0
        mov     QWORD PTR [rax+392], 0
        mov     rdx, rax
        xor     eax, eax
        and     rdi, -8
        sub     rcx, rdi
        add     ecx, 400
        shr     ecx, 3
        rep stosq
        mov     rdi, rdx
        add     rsp, 8
        jmp     operator delete[](void*)
```

Why is the output for `smart_pointer()` almost three times as large as `raw_pointer()`?

Comment: It does have a counter involved and perhaps a little overhead. Perhaps a vtable

Comment: I am actually surprised the whole thing is not optimized away altogether.

Comment: @SergeyA With clang it is.

Comment: Yes, I was checking it at the same time. Looks like CLang is starting to pick up with gcc on optimizations.

Comment: @SergeyA if it's separately compiled I guess the compiler has to allow for the possibility that you overloaded `new` and `delete` to have other side-effects?

Comment: @Leushenko, yes, certainly.

Comment: @EdHeal Counter? Vtable? That doesn't really apply to `std::unique_ptr`, does it?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Because `std::make_unique<int[]>(100)` performs [value initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) while `new int[100]` performs [default initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization) - In the first case, elements are 0-initialized (for `int`), while in the second case elements are left uninitialized. Try:

```
int *p = new int[100]();
```

And you'll get the same output as with the `std::unique_ptr`.

See [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) for instance, which states that `std::make_unique<int[]>(100)` is equivalent to:

```
std::unique_ptr<T>(new int[100]())
```

If you want a non-initialized array with `std::unique_ptr`, you could use<sup>1</sup>:

```
std::unique_ptr<int[]>(new int[100]);
```

<sub><sup>1</sup> As mentioned by [@Ruslan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22571202/differences-between-stdmake-unique-and-stdunique-ptr) in the comments, be aware of the difference between `std::make_unique()` and `std::unique_ptr()` - See [Differences between std::make_unique and std::unique_ptr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22571202/differences-between-stdmake-unique-and-stdunique-ptr).</sub>

Comment: I suspected that might be the case. Is there a way of creating a `unique_ptr` pointing to an uninitialized array?

Comment: @AlessandroPower `std::unique_ptr<int[]>(new int[100])`.

Comment: @AlessandroPower but beware of [Differences between std::make_unique and std::unique_ptr](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22571202/673852).