# How to create a new value and assign to a private unique_ptr in a class constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

How do I create new and assign a value to a private unique_ptr in the constructor of a class? Tyvm :^) Keith

My best effort:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class A {
public:
    A() {};
    A(int);
    void print();
private:
    std::unique_ptr<int> int_ptr_;
};
A::A(int a) {
    int_ptr_ = new int(a);
}
void A::print() {
    std::cout << *int_ptr_ << std::endl;
}
int main() {
    A a(10);
    a.print();
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Compiler result:

```
smartPointer2.1.cpp:13:11: error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘std::unique_ptr<int>’ and ‘int*’)
  int_ptr_ = new int(a);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Write

```
A::A(int a) : int_ptr_( new int(a) )
{
}
```

Or you could write

```
A::A(int a) 
{
    int_ptr_.reset( new int(a) );
}
```

or

```
A::A(int a) 
{
    int_ptr_ = std::make_unique<int>( a );;
}
```

The first approach is better because in the other two apart from the default constructor there is called also an additional method or the move assignment operator.

Comment: The first initializes the member variable which means it has the intended value in-place ready-to-go before the beginning of the user-supplied construction function.  I tend to prefer this approach because it means avoiding an entire class of defects that come with uninitialized variables.  On the other side, `std::make_unique` has advantages in memory layout, that shouldn't be dismissed either:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22571202/differences-between-stdmake-unique-and-stdunique-ptr

Comment: Ignore the above comment about memory layout since it only applies to `shared_ptr`.  Sutter has a nice GotW post on the general use of shared and unique pointers:  https://herbsutter.com/2013/05/29/gotw-89-solution-smart-pointers/

Comment: You can use `std::make_unique()` in the constructor initialization list, eg: `A::A(int a) : int_ptr_( std::make_unique<int>( a ) ) {}`