# Malloc vs New for Primitives

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management, malloc, new-operator

I understand the benefits of using `new` against `malloc` in C++. But for specific cases such as primitive data types (non array) - `int`, `float` etc., is it faster to use `malloc` than `new`?

Although, it is always advisable to use `new` even for primitives, if we are allocating an array so that we can use `delete[]`.

But for non-array allocation, I think there wouldn't be any constructor call for `int`? Since, `new` operator allocates memory, checks if it's allocated and then calls the constructor. But just for primitives non-array heap allocation, is it better to use `malloc` than `new`?

Please advise.

Comment: _" is it faster to use malloc than new?"_ Probably not. Even given that `new`would be implemented using `malloc` internally it likely that these calls are simply inlined.

Comment: Use neither.  Use `std::unique_ptr<T[]>` for a fixed sized dynamic array or `std::vector<T>` for a variable sized dynamic array.

Comment: Would strongly advice against using either.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Doesn't `new` have to initialize the value and `malloc` doesn't? Wouldn't that make `malloc` likely to, at least sometimes, be faster?

Comment: @david Hmm, fair point.

Comment: While others have pointed out that it is almost always better to use neither `new` nor `malloc`, it is still an interesting question if `malloc` is sometimes faster than `new`. Why not benchmark it?

Comment: @NathanOliver is there any particular benefit to `std::unique_ptr<T[]>` over `std::vector<T>` for both cases?

Comment: @Caleth Not really.  In fact `std::unique_ptr<T[]>` will initialize all elements where `std::vector` does not unless you tell it to.  The only reason I suggested `std::unique_ptr<T[]>` was because it expresses that it is a fixed sized dynamically allocated buffer.  I use `vector<T>` by default and until the profiler tells me I need to look for something else.

Comment: @NathanOliver Why would you use `std::unique_ptr`, when you have `std::array`?

Comment: @Clearer If you don't know the size until run time then you can't use `std::array`

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Never use `malloc` in C++. Never use `new` unless you are implementing a low-level memory management primitive.

The recommendation is:

- Ask yourself: *"do I need dynamic memory allocation?"*. A lot of times you might not need it - prefer **values** to pointers and try to use the stack.
- If you do need dynamic memory allocation, ask yourself *"who will own the allocated memory/object?"*.

  - If you only need a single owner *(which is very likely)*, you should
    use [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr). It is a zero cost abstraction over
    `new`/`delete`. (A different deallocator *can* be specified.)
  - If you need shared ownership, you should use [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr). This is **not** a zero cost abstraction, as it uses atomic operations and an extra "control block" to keep track of all the owners.

---

If you are dealing with arrays in particular, the Standard Library provides two powerful and safe abstractions that do not require any manual memory management:

- [`std::array<T, N>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array): a fixed array of `N` elements of type `T`.
- [`std::vector<T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector): a resizable array of elements of type `T`.

`std::array` and `std::vector` should cover 99% of your "array needs".

---

One more important thing: the Standard Library provides the [`std::make_unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) and [`std::make_shared`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared) which should **always** be used to create smart pointer instances. There are a few good reasons:

- Shorter - no need to repeat the `T` *(e.g. `std::unique_ptr<T>{new T}`)*, no need to use `new`.
- More exception safe. They prevent a potential memory leak caused by the lack of a well-defined order of evaluation in function calls. E.g.

  ```
  f(std::shared_ptr<int>(new int(42)), g())
  ```

  Could be evaluated in this order:

  1. `new int(42)`
  2. `g()`
  3. ...

  If `g()` throws, the `int` is leaked.
- More efficient (in terms of run-time speed). This only applies to `std::make_shared` - using it instead of `std::shared_ptr` directly allows the implementation to perform a single allocation both for the object and for the control block.

You can find more information in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22571202/differences-between-stdmake-unique-and-stdunique-ptr).

Comment: Might want to note that "more efficient" is in terms of speed, not necessarily memory. In particular, a `weak_ptr` would hold on to the entire memory block containing the refcount, and for a large object that might linger, that might not be so great.

Comment: I fail to see how your, even elaborated, answer has anything to do with the question. For instance, it as asked if for int/float arrays, which one is faster to use, new or malloc.

Answer (score 28):

It can still be necessary to use `malloc` and `free` in C++ when you are interacting with APIs specified using plain C, because it is *not* guaranteed to be safe to use `free` to deallocate memory allocated with `operator new` (which is ultimately what all of the managed memory classes use), nor to use `operator delete` to deallocate memory allocated with `malloc`.

A typical example is [POSIX `getline`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) (not to be confused with [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)): it takes a pointer to a `char *` variable; that variable must point to a block of memory allocated with `malloc` (or it can be NULL, in which case `getline` will call `malloc` for you); when you are done calling `getline` you are expected to call `free` on that variable.

Similarly, if you are writing a library, it can make sense to use C++ internally but define an `extern "C"` API for your external callers, because that gives you better binary interface stability and cross-language interoperability.  And if you return heap-allocated POD objects to your callers, you might want to let them deallocate those objects with `free`; they can't necessarily use `delete`, and making them call `YourLibraryFree` when there are no destructor-type operations needed is unergonomic.

It can also still be necessary to use `malloc` when *implementing* resizable container objects, because there is no equivalent of `realloc` for `operator new`.

But as the other answers say, when you don't have this kind of interface constraint tying your hands, use one of the managed memory classes instead.

Comment: Why not simply do `auto ptr = std::make_unique<T>()` and later `return ptr.release()`? Yes, it is more code, but if there's logic in between, it works nicely.

Comment: Because there's no guarantee that memory allocated by `std::make_unique()` is safe to deallocate using `free()`

Comment: Well constructed API would usually require you to provide a deallocator (as a function pointer), but alas some still don't.

Comment: anyway, you can't use realloc for implementing resizable container objects, because you can't know beforehand if your data will stay at the same address. After the call, if realloc did move your data, you're screwed because you did not call objects move constructor. You need to allocate-move-free, or call OS specific API such as HeapReAlloc with HEAP_REALLOC_IN_PLACE_ONLY flag.

Comment: @ThreeStarProgrammer57 Container resize is specifically allowed to invalidate iterators and other forms of external pointers into the container. If you write objects that care about their own addresses, you have only yourself to blame.

Comment: @zwol the problem is not external iterators or pointers. If realloc cannot realloc in place, it performs a raw memcpy to the new memory. In C++, this is wrong. Moving (or copying) an object requires calling its move (or copy) constructor. raw memcpy may work with some objects, but for any general purpose container it is not correct.

Comment: @ThreeStarProgrammer57 Objects that can't be _moved_ (not necessarily copied) with raw `memcpy` are firmly in "don't do that then" territory.

Comment: @zwol `template <typename T> class SomeContainer` is off limits then

Answer (score 8):

It's always better to use `new`. If you use `malloc` you still have to check manually if space is allocated.

In modern c++ you can use smart pointers. With `make_unique` and `make_shared` you never call `new` explicitly. `std::unique_ptr` is not bigger than the underlying pointer and the overhead of using it is minimal.

Answer (score 6):

The answer to **"should I use `new` or `malloc`"** is **single responsibillity rule**.

Resource management should be done by a type that has that as its sole purpose.
Those classes already exists, such as `unique_ptr`, `vector` etc.

Directly using either `malloc` or `new` is a cardinal sin.

Answer (score 3):

[zwol's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44595902/2445184) already gives the correct correctness answer: Use `malloc()`/`free()` when interacting with C interfaces **only**.
I'm not going to repeat those details, I'm going to answer the performance question.

The truth is, that the performance of `malloc()` and `new` can, and does differ. When you perform an allocation with `new`, the memory will generally be allocated via call to the global `operator new()` function, which is distinct from `malloc()`. It is trivial to implement `operator new()` by calling through to `malloc()`, but this is not necessarily done.

As a matter of fact, I've seen a system where an `operator new()` that calls through to `malloc()` would outperform the standard implementation of `operator new()` by roughly 100 CPU cycles per call. That's definitely a measurable difference, and a clear indication that the standard implementation does something very different from `malloc()`.

So, if you are worried about performance, there is three things to do:

1. Measure your performance.
2. Write replacement implementations for the global `operator new()` function and its friends.
3. Measure your performance and compare.

The gains/losses may or may not be significant.