# Easy C++ array assignment

Tags: c++, c++11

Sorry for the question, I have been doing Python and JS too much and am coming back to C++ now to assign an array.

How can it be done easier than this:

```
float* d1 = (float*)calloc(4,sizeof(float));
d1[0] = 1;
d1[1] = 2;
d1[2] = 3;
d1[3] = 4;
```

I am used to `d1 = [1,2,3,4]` and cannot wrap my head around it...

Comment: `::std::array<float, 4> d1{1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f, 4.0f};`

Comment: [You have virtually no reason to use the `malloc` family of functions in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44588345/malloc-vs-new-for-primitives/44588567#44588567). So don't.

Answer (score 6):

I see the following options for creating an array of `float`s.

**Option 1**

Use a regular array.

```
float d1[] = {1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f, 4.0f};
```

or

```
float d1[4] = {1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f, 4.0f};
```

**Option 2**

Use `std::array`.

```
std::array<float, 4> d1{1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f, 4.0f}
```

**Option 3**

Use `std::vector`.

```
std::vector<float> d1{1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f, 4.0f}
```

Unless there is a strong reason, prefer to use `std::array` or `std::vector`. `std::array` is appropriate if you know the size of the array at compile time. `std::vector` is appropriate if you don't know the size of the array at compile time.

One of the main benefits of using `std::array` or `std::vector` is that you have the ability to find out the size of array when the variable is used in a function call. If you use a regular array, the array decays to a pointer. You have to pass the size in another argument to help the function prevent accessing the array using an out of bounds index.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code out :

```
float array[] = {1.0f,2.0f,3.0f,4.0f};
```

This code creates a simple array of 4 elements . Upon initialization , the arrays is the following contents : `1,2,3,4` . Hope this helps .

Answer (score 0):

If the values are known at compile time

```
 float d1[4] = {1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f, 4.0f};
```

or

```
 std::array<float, 4>  d1 {1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f, 4.0f};    // since C++11
```

The simple way is, assuming values are generated at run time,

```
 std::array<float, 4> d1;                     // or float d1[4]
 for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) d1[i] = i+1.0f;

 //  or, instead of the loop, since C++11

 std::iota(std::begin(d1), std::end(d1), 1.0f);    // iota() specified in <numeric>
```

or (if the number of elements is not known until run time)

```
 std::vector<float> d1(number);
 for (int i = 0; i < number; ++i) d1[i] = i+1.0f;

 //   or, instead of the loop, since C++11

 std::iota(d1.begin(), d1.end(), 1.0f);
```