# Why pass by const reference in overload operator+ with multiple parameters

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, constants, pass-by-reference

I am doing operator+ overloading with multiple parameters as below.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Integer{
    int value;
    public:
        Integer(int i) {value=i;};
        int getValue() { return value;};
        friend Integer operator+ (Integer & a, Integer & b){
            Integer I (a.value+b.value);
            return I;
        };
};

int main() {
    Integer a(1), b(2), c(3);
    Integer d = a+b+c;
    cout<<d.getValue()<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It can't be compile and return" no match for operator+". I read and understand the algorithm of multiple parameter that ((a+b)+c). Why it does not work?
However, I found two ways to make it work:

```
friend Integer operator+ (const Integer & a,const Integer & b){
    Integer I (a.value+b.value);
    return I;
};
```

And

```
friend Integer & operator+ (Integer & a,Integer & b){
    Integer I (a.value+b.value);
    return I;
};
```

But I dont know why. Thank you

Comment: Please read about the [canonical forms](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators) of overloaded operators. It's all well-defined and well-documented.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look at your `operator+` signature:

```
friend Integer operator+ (Integer & a, Integer & b)
//                        ^^^^^^^^^    ^^^^^^^^^
```

`a` and `b` are **lvalue references**.

---

When you write

```
Integer d = a+b+c;
```

`a+b` produces an **rvalue** of type `Integer`, which does not bind to `Integer&`.

---

The version with `const Integer &` works as `const` lvalue references can be bound to both **lvalues** and **rvalues**.

Answer (score 0):

Executing `a+b+c;` will first invoke `operator +` with `a` and `b` which will produce a temporary `Integer` object, then invoke `operator +` with that temporary object and `c`. Calling `operator +` second time won't be possible because a temporary object can not be passed as reference to a non-const-qualified object.

Declaring `operator +` to accept non-const references does not make sense anyway because objects passes are not modified.