# Is it safe to init a std::unique_ptr from a local raw pointer?

Tags: c++11, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I know it's unwise to do so with a `std::shared_ptr`. But what about `std::unique_ptr`? E.g. :

```
class A {
 public:
  void do_something() { }
};

std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A> > uq_ptrs_;
auto p = new A();
uq_ptrs_.push_back(std::unique_ptr<A>(p));
p->do_something();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Differences between std::make\_unique and std::unique\_ptr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22571202/differences-between-stdmake-unique-and-stdunique-ptr)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as you don't manually `delete` the object after creating the `std::unique_ptr` (or `std::shared_ptr`!) object then it's fine.

You should also avoid dereferencing the pointer `p` once you asked the `std::unique_ptr` (or `std::shared_ptr`) to take ownership of it. Instead use the smart pointer object.

Comment: I added some more lines to the example. According to your newly added comment, `p->do_something();` shouldn't be there?

Comment: @duong_dajgja As long as the `std::unique_ptr` object still exists, then you *can* use the raw pointer like you do. However, I strongly recommend against it. I also strongly recommend you *don't* do like you do with a raw non-owning pointer that you at a later point move ownership to a `std::unique_ptr`. Instead *start* with a `std::unique_ptr`. What you're doing is saying that the object pointed to by `p` is *owned* by the new `std::unique_ptr` object.