# How do I switch this to unique_ptr?

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr

How do I make it so I dont have to manually delete the pointer?

With `unique_ptr` in the `vector<>` ?

Here is my code:

```cpp
class vec2 {
 public:
  double x;
  double y;

  vec2() {
    x = 0.0;
    y = 0.0;
  }

  vec2(double xx, double yy) {
    x = xx;
    y = yy;
    cout << "constructor called" << endl;
  }

  ~vec2() {
    static int count = 0;
    cout << "destructor " << count << endl;
    count++;
  }

  virtual double Length() { return sqrt(x * x + y * y); }

  bool operator==(vec2& v) { return x == v.x && y == v.y; }

  virtual string toString() {
    stringstream s("");
    s << "[" << x << " " << y << "]";
    return s.str();
  }
};

int main() {
  vector<vec2*> vecs;
  vecs.push_back(new vec2(1.8, 1.7));
  vecs.push_back(new vec2(1.99, 1.7));
  for (vec2* v : vecs) {
    cout << v->toString() << endl;
    delete v;
  }
}
```

http://www.xgdev.com/notepad/textfiles/37631a.txt

Comment: how about not using pointers and making it a `std::vector<vec2>`?

Comment: if i do it plain vec2 it is slower and constructor and destructor gets called more times, less efficient.

Comment: @Thomas, probably `virtual` methods are there for a reason.

Comment: there is a vec3 class too, but I didnt include it. vec3 inherits from vec2

Comment: @Evgeny missed that. but there prob. is no need for it. ... the OP should make his destructor virtual then ...

Comment: @Thomas, totally agree. There should be no inheritance from `vec2` and no `virtual`s. But that's another question.

Comment: @user366866: have you _measured_ the performance difference? Copying two doubles is a breeze compared to heap allocation and bad locality you get by having allocations scattered around.

Comment: You will actually be faster when using vector<vec2> instead of using pointers. What makes your pointers slow is that you allocate a new one for every item in the vector. This is very bad for memory layout, your pointers will end up being all over the place, resulting in cache misses. A straight linear layout, like you get with vector<vec2> will be much faster and even easier to maintain.

Answer (score 2):

Simple:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<vec2>> vecs;
vecs.reserve(2);   // Optional
vecs.push_back(std::make_unique<vec2>(1.8 ,1.7));
vecs.push_back(std::make_unique<vec2>(1.99, 1.7));
for (auto& v : vecs) {
    cout << v->toString() << endl;
}
```

If you have `virtual` member function(s), most probably, destructor should also be `virtual`.

Comment: is the copy constructor called?

Comment: @user366866, no.

Comment: how about using `emplace_back` and reserving?

Comment: 1. `reserve` - probably, yes. 2. If `std::make_unique` is used, `emplace_back` and `push_back` are equivalent (for example, in Microsoft STL the overload of `push_back` taking `T&&` simply calls `emplace_back`), `emplace_back` can be used with `new`: `emplace_back(new vec2(1, 2))`, but `make_unique` is better, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22571202/differences-between-stdmake-unique-and-stdunique-ptr