# Differences between std::make_unique and std::unique_ptr with new internally

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

This question is a follow up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22571202/5909613).

[The accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22571331/5909613) states:

> `make_unique` is safe for creating temporaries whereas with explicit use of `new` you have to remember the rule about not using unnamed temporaries

I get the rough idea what is meant by this and I understand the example given, but how exactly does this work internally? What do these functions do exactly and where is the difference?

Comment: Have a read of https://herbsutter.com/gotw/_102/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What do these functions do exactly and where is the difference?

Nothing magical actually. They just transform user code from this:

```
f( std::unique_ptr<T1>{ new T1 }, std::unique_ptr<T2>{ new T2 } );
```

Into this:

```
f( make_unique<T1>(), make_unique<T2>() );
```

Just to avoid the scenario where the compiler orders the actions like the following, because it may do so until C++14 (included):

- `new T1`
- `new T2`
- build first `unique_ptr`
- build second `unique_ptr`

If the second step (`new T2`) throws an exception, the first allocated object has not yet been secured into a `unique_ptr` and leaks.

The `make_unique` function is actually simple to write, and has been overlooked for C++11. It has been easily introduced in C++14. Inbetween, everybody would write their own `make_unique` template, or google the one written by Stephen T. Lavavej.

As StoryTeller commented, since C++17, this interleaving is no more allowed.

Comment: That sort of interleaving is not legal since C++17. A leak can't happen that way on a conformant C++17 compiler (though I still find repeating the type name bad on itself).

Comment: @StoryTeller: I didn't check, but are there deduction guides in C++17 for `unique_ptr`?

Comment: There aren't, and even the compiler generated ones are disabled by design. Chiefly because the deduction guide can't tell apart if it should deduce `T*` or `T[]` based on the argument to the constructor alone.