# Why is std::make_unique necessary to initialize member std::unique array, and how to work around for C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, unique-ptr

In the following code, why is `std::make_unique` necessary to initialize `Foo::up_`?
Specifically, **why doesn't initializing `Foo::up_` with `new Bar(...)` -- as in the commented-out code -- work?**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

enum E {
  Y = 0,
  Z = 1,
  NUM_E
};

class Bar {
public: // Functions
  Bar( const int& i, const int& j ) : i_(i), j_(j) { }

public: // Objects
  int i_;
  int j_;
};

class Foo {
public: // Functions
  Foo();

  void reset( const int& Yi, const int& Yj,
              const int& Zi, const int& Zj );

public: // Objects
  std::unique_ptr<Bar> up_[NUM_E];
};

Foo::Foo()
  : up_{ std::make_unique<Bar>( 42, 43 ),
         std::make_unique<Bar>( 44, 45 ) }
//  : up_{ new Bar( 42, 43 ),
//         new Bar( 44, 45 ) } // err: could not convert from Bar* to unique_ptr
{ }

void Foo::reset( const int& Yi, const int& Yj,
                 const int& Zi, const int& Zj ) {
  up_[Y].reset( new Bar( Yi, Yj ) );
  up_[Z].reset( new Bar( Zi, Zj ) );
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] ) {
  (void)argc;
  (void)argv;
  Foo foo;

  std::cout << foo.up_[Y]->i_ << std::endl;
  std::cout << foo.up_[Y]->j_ << std::endl;
  std::cout << foo.up_[Z]->i_ << std::endl;
  std::cout << foo.up_[Z]->j_ << std::endl;

  foo.reset( 1, 2, 3, 4 );

  std::cout << foo.up_[Y]->i_ << std::endl;
  std::cout << foo.up_[Y]->j_ << std::endl;
  std::cout << foo.up_[Z]->i_ << std::endl;
  std::cout << foo.up_[Z]->j_ << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

```
$ g++ --version && g++ --std=c++14 ./main.cpp && ./a.out
g++ (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 6.3.0 20170516
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

42
43
44
45
1
2
3
4
```

**How does one work around this for `C++11`, where `std::make_unique` doesn't appear to be available?**

```
$ g++ --version && g++ --std=c++11 ./main.cpp && ./a.out
g++ (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 6.3.0 20170516
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

./main.cpp: In constructor ‘Foo::Foo()’:
./main.cpp:31:10: error: ‘make_unique’ is not a member of ‘std’
   : up_{ std::make_unique<Bar>( 42, 43 ),
          ^~~
./main.cpp:31:30: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
   : up_{ std::make_unique<Bar>( 42, 43 ),
                              ^
./main.cpp:32:10: error: ‘make_unique’ is not a member of ‘std’
          std::make_unique<Bar>( 44, 45 ) }
          ^~~
./main.cpp:32:30: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
          std::make_unique<Bar>( 44, 45 ) }
                              ^
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. The constructor [`unique_ptr( pointer p )`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr) is marked `explicit`, which prevents instances of `unique_ptr` from being constructed implicitly in array list initialization.

2. `std::make_unique` is available since C++14.

In C++11 a possible solution to both points is to construct an instance explicitly e.g. `std::unique_ptr<Bar>(new Bar( 42, 43 ))`.

Comment: @StoneThrow there is none in this context. You can have one, pre-C++17, under some narrow circumstances, more details here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55509661/differences-between-stdmake-unique-and-stdunique-ptr-with-new-internally/55510149

Answer (score 4):

The reason why you can't construct your array of `unique_ptr's` from array initializer of simple pointers is because `unique_ptr` pointer constructor is [explicit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr).

To fix this issue, you could either call explicit constructors of `unique_ptr`s, but that's quite boring and prone to issues which prompted adding `make_unique` in the first place. Instead, you can simple have your own `compat::make_unique` template function, which is literally 1 line:

```
template<class T, class... Args>
std::unique_ptr<T> make_unique(Args&&... args) {
    return std::unique_ptr<T>(new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have make_unique, you can just use the constructor of unique_ptr like this

```
Foo::Foo()
  : up_{ std::unique_ptr<Bar>(new Bar( 42, 43 )),
         std::unique_ptr<Bar>(new Bar( 44, 45 )) }
{ }
```

https://godbolt.org/z/G9f5v1

Comment: This question fails to answer most interesting aspect: "why is std::make_unique necessary to initialize Foo::up_?"

Comment: @MooingDuck not in this context, though.

Comment: My understanding was that In C++11, the compiler is allowed to execute the `new Bar(32, 43)`, and then it can attempt to execute `new Bar(44, 45)`, which can throw a `std::bad_alloc`, which can unwind the stack. But the first `Bar(32, 43)` will not be deleted because it was not yet assigned to a unique_ptr. This ordering issue was updated in C++17.  Can you remind me what I'm overlooking? 

Comment: @MooingDuck yes, I understand this is your understanding, and your understanding is incorrect. Unspecified order of evaluation only applies to function calls. In the example above, there is no function call, there is a braced-list-initialization, and for braced list initialization, `"every value computation and side effect of a given initializer clause is sequenced before every value computation and side effect associated with any initializer clause that follows it in the brace-enclosed comma-separated list of initalizers"`.

Comment: @SergeyA: Aha! Thanks for correcting me! I was unaware of this clause!