# std::unique_ptr constructor behaviour

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, move-semantics

First of all, I know that we should use `std::make_unique()` instead of calling the `std::unique_ptr` constructor and I know why.

But I was looking at the documentation of `std::unique_ptr` to pass the time and sharpen my knowledge about it and I found the [following examples](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr/) about the constructor usage:

```
// unique_ptr constructor example
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

int main () {
  std::default_delete<int> d;
  std::unique_ptr<int> u1;
  std::unique_ptr<int> u2 (nullptr);
  std::unique_ptr<int> u3 (new int);
  std::unique_ptr<int> u4 (new int, d);
  std::unique_ptr<int> u5 (new int, std::default_delete<int>());
  std::unique_ptr<int> u6 (std::move(u5));
  std::unique_ptr<int> u7 (std::move(u6));
  std::unique_ptr<int> u8 (std::auto_ptr<int>(new int));

  std::cout << "u1: " << (u1?"not null":"null") << '\n';
  std::cout << "u2: " << (u2?"not null":"null") << '\n';
  std::cout << "u3: " << (u3?"not null":"null") << '\n';
  std::cout << "u4: " << (u4?"not null":"null") << '\n';
  std::cout << "u5: " << (u5?"not null":"null") << '\n';
  std::cout << "u6: " << (u6?"not null":"null") << '\n';
  std::cout << "u7: " << (u7?"not null":"null") << '\n';
  std::cout << "u8: " << (u8?"not null":"null") << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

It generates (and I verified it by executing the code) the following results:

> u1: null
>   u2: null
>   u3: not null
>   u4: not null
>   u5: null
>   u6: null
>   u7: not null
>   u8: not null

What I'm struggling to understand is:

- Why is `u4` valid while `u5` is not (`nullptr`) ?
- Why is `u7` valid but not `u6` ?

Perhaps these questions are very basic but I'm completely missing the point.

If anyone could enlighten me about these questions, I would be grateful.

Comment: `u5` died while initializing `u6`, and *then* `u6` died while initializing `u7`. `std::unique_ptr` will become null when moved from, by design, to enforce its guarantee of unique ownership.

Comment: @AlanBirtles TLDR: exception safety when creating multiple unique_ptr variables as function arguments and one of them throws. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/22571331/256138

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why is u4 valid while u5 is not (nullptr) ?

Because `u5` was moved from in the initialisation of `u6`, while `u4` has not been moved from. The move constructor is guaranteed to set the moved from pointer to null. It cannot point to the same object as `u6` since that would violate the uniqueness constraint.

> Why is u7 valid but not u6 ?

Same reason.

Comment: Oh right, I'm so stupid... tired. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 6):

`std::move` is named `move` for a reason. When you move from one `std::unique_ptr` to another, the one you move from becomes nullptr. It couldn't be any other way, it's a *unique* ptr after all, and two `unique_ptr` instances sharing the same data would violate that. (Also both going out of scope would call the deleter twice, and then all hell is loose.)

Answer (score 3):

Moving a uniquely owned object means that the new owner has it and the previous owner has nothing left.
Much like how physical objects work in the real world.

Having nothing is indicated by the owner’s converting to a null pointer.

The object that was initially owned by `u5` has been moved first into `u6` and then into `u7`.