# Segmentation fault with unique_ptr

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, unique-ptr

I am trying to use unique_ptr instead of allocating memory myself.
I have the following code:

```
class Album {
...
public:
    Add(Song* song);
...
}

void func(){
    ...
    std::unique_ptr<Album> album = std::unique_ptr<Album>{new Album()};
    std::unique_ptr<Song> song = std::unique_ptr<Song>{new Song(soundtrack.data(), soundtrack.length())};
    album->Add(song.get());
    ...
}
```

I get segmentation fault for the line:

```
album->Add(song.get());
```

I tried multiple variations to get the pointer, including std::move and make_unique, but maybe I don't understand how unique_ptr works well enough to solve it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does that even compile? A member function needs a return type.

Comment: `Add` should probably take `std::unique_ptr<Song>` and not `Song*`. Then you'll have to `std::move`: `album->Add(std::move(song));`.

Comment: @Evg not neccessarily: If you're not taking ownership it's completely reasonable to take a raw pointer as argument. See also this [GotW](https://herbsutter.com/2013/06/05/gotw-91-solution-smart-pointer-parameters/).

Comment: @andreee, absolutely! But the the logic here suggests that it is `Album` that is responsible for songs, not `func`.

Comment: @O.B. I think you need to provide more information. Most probably your `album` is outliving the `song` instance, due to a misuse of `unique_ptr` (as mentioned by Evg). Side note: [You should prefer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22571202/differences-between-stdmake-unique-and-stdunique-ptr-with-new) `make_unique` over calling `new` in the ctor.

Comment: The point of the smart "pointers" is not managing memory but managing *ownership*; they are almost entirely dissimilar from actual pointers. They are not magic pixie dust that saves you from thinking about lifetimes and owners. Using a raw pointer that you acquired with `get` suffers from many of the same problems as using one you acquired with `&`.

Comment: @O.B. maybe _you_ should read the [GotW](https://herbsutter.com/2013/06/05/gotw-91-solution-smart-pointer-parameters/) I referred to in my previous comment, it should help you to gain a better understanding of smart pointers and how to use them properly. In particular Guru question 3.

Comment: @acraig5075 yes my mistake not including it. This is part of a much bigger code.

Comment: @andreee I will take a look at it. I do not want to change the signature of the function. Maybe my usuage of unique_ptr is incorrect. What I tried to achieve is to not manage the memory of the song and album, and de-allocate songs when they are removed from album (no more owners).

Comment: @O.B. you may take a look at the `unique_ptr::release` function then. It allows you to transform a unique pointer into an owning raw pointer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is as follows

```
class Album {
...
public:
    Add(Song* song);
...
}

void func(){
    ...
    std::unique_ptr<Album> album = std::unique_ptr<Album>{new Album()};
    std::unique_ptr<Song> song = std::unique_ptr<Song>{new Song(soundtrack.data(), soundtrack.length())};
    album->Add(song.get());
    ...
    // Here the object song gets destructed. This means that the underlying Song gets destructed.
    // So right after leaving func() the pointer that was returned by song.get() now points to non-allocated memory containing random bits at worst case.
}
```

So one possible solution would be...

```
class Album {
...
public:
    Add(std::unique_ptr<Song> song); // you still need to move song inside Add(...)
...
}

void func(){
    ...
    std::unique_ptr<Album> album = std::unique_ptr<Album>{new Album()};
    std::unique_ptr<Song> song = std::unique_ptr<Song>{new Song(soundtrack.data(), soundtrack.length())};
    album->Add(std::move(song)); //here song is intended  to be moved inside Add(...)
    ...
    // song points to nullptr here.
}
```

Comment: You may show your version of _Add()_ so that one can show you how to adapt it in detail.

Comment: You should not be passing unique pointers as rvalues, pass them by value instead

Comment: Or as a non-const ref, if you want to sink the value.

Answer (score 1):

The code you provided compiles and runs fine - thus there must be a problem in the part you didnot provide - I suspect code inside `Add()` or it's returntype, or some later use of the pointers as [necktschnagge](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6346852/necktschnagge) suspected. Working example is on gdbonline:
https://onlinegdb.com/r1oyXGK2S

First of all I ask the question, *what is the advantage you'll like to achive* by use of `std::unique_ptr`. Consider that a unique pointer does not guarantee to have a pointee - inside `Add()` you have to check for `nullptr`!
I think from your usage, you do not want to use a `std::unique_ptr`:

Key is, that a `std::unique_ptr` has just a unique ownership. either one of those:

- `func()`::local scope
- `album::Add()`::parameter_scope

ownes it.

Since you didn't use `std::move()` the ownership remains in `func()`, and will be destroyed by the end of `func()`. To avoid this you might as well use `song.release()` (see  [cpp-reference](https://de.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/release)).