# I can't push_back a unique_ptr after passed it into a function

Tags: c++, vector, unique-ptr, push-back

I'm working on my little project about pointers, I ran into problem when I was trying to push a unique_ptr to a derived class, to a vector of unique_ptr to base class. It keeps saying that I'm "attempting to reference to a deleted function". I tried to use push_back with and without std::move but nothing worked...

```
#include<iostream>
#include<memory>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

class Base {};
class Derived : public Base {};

void add(vector<unique_ptr<Base>> list, const unique_ptr<Base>& ptr);

int main()
{
    vector<unique_ptr<Base>> list;
    unique_ptr<Base> derived(new Derived);
    add(list, derived);
}

void add(vector<unique_ptr<Base>> list, const unique_ptr<Base>& ptr)
{
    list.push_back(move(ptr));
}
```

Comment: `add(vector<unique_ptr<Base>> list` is a copy, I guess you don't intend it.

Comment: `list.push_back(move(ptr))` const can't be moved.

Answer (score 3):

There are quite a few issues with your code:

- please don't use `using namespace std`. See [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)
- you copy the vector. Because it contains non-copyable items, the vector itself is non-copyable:

  ```
  void add(vector<unique_ptr<Base>> list, const unique_ptr<Base>& ptr);
  //                              ^
  ```
- you can't move from const objects:

  ```
  void add(vector<unique_ptr<Base>> list, const unique_ptr<Base>& ptr);
  //                                      ^~~~~                 ~
  ```
- use `std::make_unique`. See [Differences between std::make_unique and std::unique_ptr with new](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22571202/differences-between-stdmake-unique-and-stdunique-ptr-with-new)
- `unique_ptr` cannot be copied so you need to move it:

  ```
  add(list, derived);
  ```

Here is the code corrected:

```
void add(std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>>& list, std::unique_ptr<Base> ptr)
{
    list.push_back(std::move(ptr));
}
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>> list;
    std::unique_ptr<Base> derived = std::make_unique<Derived>();

    add(list, std::move(derived));
}

// or

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>> list;

    add(list, std::make_unique<Derived>());
}
```

Comment: but i don't understand why we can't pass unique_ptr by ref?

Comment: @DucNguyen you can pass by ref, just not by constant ref, nor lvalue ref. You can pass by rvalue ref (a.k.a. `&&`). The reason is because moving from an object modifies that object (to reflect the new state - moved from) so you cannot move from const.

Comment: oh, i see, that was harder than I thought