# Why does C++ need std::make_unique over forwarded unique_ptr constructor?

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

I **don't** ask about `new operator` like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22571202/differences-between-stdmake-unique-and-stdunique-ptr-with-new). Please, read question carefully.

I want to know why we need special function `make_unique` over special constructor
of unique_ptr.

`unique_ptr` could use constructor like this to make `make_unique` unneccessary:

```cpp
template<typename T, typename ...TArgs>
unique_ptr::unique_ptr(TArgs&&... args)
        : inner_ptr(new T(std::forward(args)...))
{}
```

Comment: IIRC it was originaly added to pair well with [`std::make_shared`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared).

Comment: It allows T to be deduced: `std::make_unique(some_function())` is shorter than `std::unique_ptr<WHATEVER_SOME_FUNCTION_RETURNS>(some_function())`. This predated CTAD.

Comment: @RaymondChen - `T` must be specified explicitly in every overload of `make_unique<T>`

Comment: @UnslanderMonica You're right. Yet I remember doing it. Maybe it was just a dream. Here's [the original proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3588.txt) for rationale behind `make_unique`. Also, your proposed `unique_ptr` constructor would be ambiguous: Consider `struct S { S(S* parent = nullptr); }; p1 = new S(); p2 = std::unique_ptr<S>(p1);`. Is this creating a `unique_ptr` to manage the existing `p1`? Or is this creating a `unique_ptr` to create a new `S` which has the `p1` as its parent?

Comment: @RaymondChen - I'm not the person who asked this question. Was just pondering upon an answer when your comment popped up so I responded. I agree with your point about the ambiguity.

Comment: @RaymondChen template parameter T must be proposed in make_unique too, TArgs parameter can be deduced as it does in make_unique.

Comment: @RaymondChen In for your example, there would run overload resolution rules which would choose more suitable constructor of unique_ptr (the one which takes pointer into ownership).

Comment: @AngelicosPhosphoros - You entirely missed Raymond's point. It isn't about the *technicality* of an ambiguity, it's about the declaration being unclear to anyone reading it since the semantics of the unique pointer and the S are in conflict. Furthermore, it's not impossible to construct examples that **would be** ambiguous to the compiler too. And SFINAEing the whole thing would be a nightmare to an implementer.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Thanks for the explanation. This is more clear for me now.

Comment: Well, I sometimes wonder, why mods don't ever try to read disclaimer written especially for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I want to summarize discussion with [Some programmer dude](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440558/some-programmer-dude), [StoryTeller - Unslander Monica](https://stackoverflow.com/users/817643/storyteller-unslander-monica) and [Raymond Chen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/902497/raymond-chen)

So, there are 2 reasons:

1. `std::make_unique` pairs well with [std::make_shared](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared) which was introduced earlier so this was easier to learn than new constructor for `unique_ptr`.
2. There is possible ambiguity between constructor of `unique_ptr` and constructor of inner value type (`T`) if this type have own constructor which takes a pointer to self type. E.g.

```cpp
struct Inner{
  Inner() = default;
  Inner(Inner* parent_node): parent(parent_node){}
  
  Inner* parent = nullptr;
};


Inner* parent = make_parent();
// It would be not clear for human which constructor must be called here
std::unique_ptr<Inner> child(parent);
```

Compiler can deduce which constructor should be called here but it is hard for human. So having function `std::make_unique` is beneficial because it is clear that all constructors of `std::unique_ptr` create only unique_ptr and never call inner value constructor while `std::make_unique` would always call constructor of inner value. This makes code much easier to reason about.

Thanks to everyone for discussion!

Answer (score 6):

There's a couple of reasons for this.

The first has to do with a bit of C++ history. Prior to C++17, there was no exception safety with the constructor, so doing the following:

```cpp
some_func(std::unique_ptr<T1>(), std::unique_ptr<T2>())
```

would leak memory were the constructor for T1 to throw an exception, as the C++ standard did not require that, in this case the first unique_ptr, should have it's memory deallocated. This is no longer the case since C++17

Second, it allows for a more general rule of "never to use `new`" which without `make_unique` would be "never use `new` except for when using `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr`"

Also there's the added bonus of no redundant typing, as with the constructor you have to do:

```cpp
auto p = std::unique_ptr<T>(new T());
```

listing `T` twice, which can be particularly ugly in the case of long type names. With `make_unique` this shortens to

```cpp
auto p = std::make_unique<T>();
```

Comment: Thanks. The latter can be achieved by my constructor too as well.
`auto p = std::unique_ptr<MyType>(my_type_arg1, my_type_arg2);`

Comment: >Prior to C++17, there was no exception safety with the constructor, so doing the following:

Where can I read more about this?

Comment: *"Prior to C++17, there was no exception safety with the constructor"* - Your example doesn't apply to the pre-C++17 problem. Things like `std::unique_ptr<T1>(new T1), std::unique_ptr<T2>(new T2)` were unsafe, but this is not what the OP is suggesting. The `new` happens **inside the c'tor** of `unique_ptr`, as part of its execution. And just like regular function calls, there can be no interleaving.

Comment: Put another way, if the OP's suggestion is unsafe, then so is `make_unique`!

Comment: @AngelicosPhosphoros see [this](https://herbsutter.com/gotw/_102/)

Comment: @msimonelli I posted in my answer that my constructor already solves this problem because allocation happens inside of my proposed constructor.