# Passing Python large integers (>256bits) to and from C++ with pybind11

Tags: python, c++, pybind11, bignum

I'm developing a python wrapper for C++ based cryptography scheme where the keys and ciphertext are very large numbers (up to 2048 bits).

In C++, I'm using [Intel BigNumber class](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/ipp-crypto-reference/top/appendix-a-support-functions-and-classes/classes-and-functions-used-in-examples/bignumber-class.html) to store and handle such large numbers.

As Python natively supports "seemingly" infinite bits of integer through objects, I'm having trouble passing such variables as parameters via Python.

```
  py::class_<BigNumber>(m, "BigNumber")
      .def(py::init<unsigned int>())
      .def(py::init<int>())
      .def(py::init<BigNumber>())
      .def(py::init([](py::list data) {
        size_t length = data.size();
        unsigned int* pData = new unsigned int[length];
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
          pData[i] = data[i].cast<unsigned int>();
        }
        return std::unique_ptr<BigNumber>(new BigNumber(pData, length));
      }))
      .def(py::init([](py::array_t<unsigned int> data) {
        py::buffer_info buffer_info = data.request();

        unsigned int* pData = static_cast<unsigned int*>(buffer_info.ptr);
        std::vector<ssize_t> shape = buffer_info.shape;
        return std::unique_ptr<BigNumber>(new BigNumber(pData, shape[0]));
      }))
```

Above portion allows up to 32 bits single variable or a list/array of broken down large integer (each 32bit)

What if I want to take very large integers from Python as an input to fill the `BigNumber` class, and also what should I do to define a `def_property_readonly()` function that returns as a Python understandable large integer object?

Edit1: Passing large integer from Python to C++
With the help of `BigNumber(const char* s)` constructor, it can be done by:

```
      .def(py::init([](py::object obj){
        std::string s_obj = py::str(obj);
        return std::unique_ptr<BigNumber>(new BigNumber(&s_obj[0]));
      }))
```

Figuring out how to do reverse, probably `std::string` to `py::object` with `py::cast`?

Comment: I'm a hack. I turn big numbers into strings when I need to move data between programs and languages.

Comment: `C/C++` -- There is no such language.  It's either C or C++.

Comment: I found a way to pass large integer from python to C++ using ```BigNumber(const char* s);``` constructor.  Convert ```py::object obj``` to string with ```py::str(obj)``` then use the char* constructor.

Comment: Note that converting between decimal and binary actually has a really bad asymptotic runtime, so if you're going to go through a string representation, at least try to use hex or binary or something instead of decimal.

Comment: You're my kind of hack. Going with a string is simple and damn near foolproof. It's a great place to start (and stay if there are no performance concerns). Small recommendation: replace `return std::unique_ptr<BigNumber>(new BigNumber(&s_obj[0]));` with `return std::make_unique(s_obj.c_str());`. [There's less room for error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22571202/differences-between-stdmake-unique-and-stdunique-ptr-with-new).

Comment: If you change to using `GMP` for numbers at the C level (pretty sure there are C++ wrappers), there's probably a direct way to create instances of `gmpy2.xmpz` (the mutable one) or `gmpy2.mpz` (immutable, which means you definitely have to copy - but then, you might have to anyway). Even if you don't, you could probably check how *it* does the `int`<->`mpz` conversions ...

Answer (score 4):

Answer for first case:
**Passing very large integer(>256bits) object from Python to C++ with BigNumber**

Passing large integer from Python to C++ With the help of `BigNumber(const char* s)` constructor, it can be done by:

```
.def(py::init([](py::object obj){
  std::string s_obj = py::str(obj);
  return std::make_unique<BigNumber>(s_obj.c_str());
}))
```

However, returning to Python with a large integer object is still WIP

I tried returning to python with `py::int_` as:

```
.def("val", [](BigNumber const& self){
  std::string s_hex;
  self.num2hex(s_hex);
  return py::int_(s_hex);
})
```

However this invokes the same value error when you try

```
>>> int("0x12345")
```

in Python.

`ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0x12345'`