# Can't access private constructor from a friend class

Tags: c++, friend-class, private-constructor

In the following code snippet, g++ compiler outputs the following error:

> error: ‘B::B(const string&)’ is private within this context   857 |
> { return unique_ptr<_Tp>(new _Tp(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...)); }

Commenting out the line where smart pointers are used seem to work. However, I'm not sure why it works for the other cases, and still not work for the smart pointer case.

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include "string"

class A;

class B
{
    friend class A;
    B(const std::string& dummyString) { std::cout << dummyString << std::endl; }
};

class A
{
public:
    A()
    {
        B b("dummy1");
        B* pB1 = new B("dummy2");
        std::unique_ptr<B> pB2 = std::make_unique<B>("dummy3");
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
}
```

Comment: Because `std::make_unique` is not a member of `A` and therefore not a friend of `B`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `make_unique` which is supposed to construct an instance of `B` is not a friend of `B`. Therefore it does **not** have access to `B`'s private constructor.

You can use the following to achieve something similar:

```
std::unique_ptr<B> pB2 = std::unique_ptr<B>(new B("dummy3"));
```

In general it is advised to prefer `make_unique` to calling `new` yourself, and I do not encourage it in any way (see here: [Differences between std::make_unique and std::unique_ptr with new](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22571202/differences-between-stdmake-unique-and-stdunique-ptr-with-new)).
But if you are bound to this specific class hirarchy it will solve your issue.

Answer (score 2):

The **problem** is that `make_unique` internally uses the private constructor `B::B(const std::string& )`. But since `make_unique` itself is not a friend of `A`, we get the mentioned error.

To solve this you can either get rid of `make_unique` and directly use `unique_ptr` with `new` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73081486/12002570) or make the ctor `public`.