# Why aren't there memory leaks for std::unique_ptr initialized by new since C++17?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, c++17, unique-ptr

Let me quote part of the section in *Professional C++ 5th. ed.*(Page 237):

> Before C++17, you had to use `make_unique()` ...
> Consider the following call to a function called foo():
>
> `foo(unique_ptr<Simple> { new Simple{} }, unique_ptr<Bar> { new Bar { data() } });`
>
> If the constructor of `Simple` or `Bar`, or the `data()`
> function, throws an exception, depending on your compiler
> optimizations, it was possible that either a `Simple` or a `Bar` object
> would be leaked. With `make_unique()`, nothing would leak:
>
> `foo(make_unique<Simple>(), make_unique<Bar>(data()))`
>
> Since C++17, both
> calls to `foo()` are safe, but I still recommend using `make_unique()` as
> it results in code that is easier to read.

I know why it's not safe before C++17 since `new` may happen first and `data()` may be called then before the `new`'d result is passed to `unique_ptr`, so when an exception throws, memory leaks happen. But why does it become safe since C++17?

Comment: They changed the rules, see the papers at the bottom of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22571331/4342498)

Comment: TLDR: sequence is changed in C++17, function parameter order evaluation is guaranteed, and each function parameter is guaranteed to be evaluated before the next one.

Comment: When you say *`new` may happen first and `data()` may be called then before the `new`'d result is passed to `unique_ptr`, so when an exception throws, memory leaks happen*, you are thinking of the subexpression `unique_ptr<Bar>{ new Bar { data() } }`. But this is not correct; all versions of C++ handle an exception in this case without leaving a memory leak. The problem before C++17 is that one `new`'d object can be completed, and before being attached to its `unique_ptr`, the other argument expression throws an exception. C++17 forbids this.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Each is fully evaluated after the next one, but in which order is importantly still indeterminate.