# Smart pointers to an object explicitly created object

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I have read a lot of issues created in regard to this but was not able to answer my question.

I have created a class as follows -

```
class exampleClass{
public: 
    exampleClass(int n){
        cout<<"Created Class"<<endl;
        this->number = n;
    }

    ~exampleClass(){
        cout<<endl<<"This class is destroyed Now"<<endl;
    }

    template<typename t> t 
    addNum(t a, t b){
        return a + b;
    }

    void print(){
        cout<<this->number<<endl;
    }
private:
    int number;
};
```

and I make 2 `shared_ptr`(or for that matter `unique_ptr`, error is same) as follows -

```
int main(){
   exampleClass* object = new exampleClass(60);

   std::shared_ptr<exampleClass> p1(object);
   std::shared_ptr<exampleClass> p2 (object);
   p1->print();
}
```

Now the error it throws at the end is -

```
free(): double free detected in tcache 2
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I am not able to understand why the error at the end. Shouldn't the above code be equal to `p2 =p1`(in case of `shared_ptr`) or `p2 = std::move(p1)` for `unique_ptr` as both the pointers are for the same object?

TIA 
PS - The title might be a little misleading or not accurate,but I did not know what exactly should be a title.

Comment: How the compiler can guess p2 = p1 if you have coded p2 = object? It does exactly what you coded.

Comment: Creating a `shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr` from a raw pointer means that the created smart "pointer" now owns the object pointed to and you're not allowed to hand over ownership to it to anything else. (It's kind of like giving away your car; you can only do that once, then the new owner gets to decide what to do with it.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the usefulness of \`enable\_shared\_from\_this\`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712279/what-is-the-usefulness-of-enable-shared-from-this)

Comment: You have learned one of the reasons there should be 0 occurrences of `new` in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a `shared_ptr` from a raw pointer, it takes ownership of the raw pointer, and when the smart pointer goes out of scope, it will call delete on the owned resource. Giving the same raw pointer to 2 different `shared_ptr`s causes a double free, as both of them will try to free the resource.

If you need 2 `shared_ptr`s that share the same resource, you can copy the first one:

```cpp
int main(){
   exampleClass* object = new exampleClass(60);

   std::shared_ptr<exampleClass> p1(object);
   std::shared_ptr<exampleClass> p2 = p1;
}
```

This way they share ownership of the resource (`sharaed_ptr`s have an internal reference counter that tracks how many of them own a resource. When you copy a `shared_ptr`, the reference counter is incremented. When one goes out of scope, the reference counter is decremented. Only if the counter reaches zero is the resource freed) thus it will only be freed once, when the last `shared_ptr` owning the resource goes out of scope.

It's usually preferable to avoid explicitly writing out `new` and use `make_shared`, which does the allocation, creates the object for you and returns a `shared_ptr` that owns it:

```cpp
auto object = std::make_shared<exampleClass>(60);
```

Some additional advanced reading in the topic, not strictly related to the question:

- performance differences when using `make_shared` vs manually calling `new`: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9302296/is-make-shared-really-more-efficient-than-new#:%7E:text=make_shared%20is%20(in%20practice)%20more,variable%20for%20the%20reference%20count.)
- memory implications of using `make_shared` with `weak_ptr`s and large objects: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32113594/weak-ptr-make-shared-and-memory-deallocation) (Thanks for bringig this up @Yakk - Adam Nevraumont, this was new for me :))

Comment: You might want to mention the make shared weak ptr and large object issue

Answer (score 3):

When you create a smart pointer, it will take ownership of the pointer, and deletes it when it goes out of scope (or when the last reference is done in case of a shared pointer).
When you create two smart pointers from the same raw pointer they both will delete the pointer at the end of their life, because they don't know about each other.

```
int main()
{
    // Create a shared pointer with a new object
   std::shared_ptr<exampleClass> p1 = std::make_shared<exampleClass>(60);

   // Now you can safely create a second pointer from your existing one.
   std::shared_ptr<exampleClass> p2 = p1;
   p1->print();
   p2->print();
}
```